# SQL Join issue with two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT tablea.z, count(tablea.z), count(tableb.y)
FROM tablea
JOIN tableb
ON tablea.y = tableb.y
GROUP BY tablea.z;
```

I'm trying to ultimately get `count(tableb.y)/count(tablea.z)`.

Each one works fine when I find them individually but when I join the tables as shown above, `count(tablea.z)` turns into `count(tableb.y)`.

Any tips?

Comment: This is because the SELECT list has already performed the join and returned the joined set... thus, both counts are returning the number of rows resultant of the join.  There's a few ways around this... knowing which SQL engine you're working with would help.

Comment: Can you show us some sample input and output?

Comment: @jdl134679 MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to evaluate the 2 table counts independently of each other:

I may have what you are trying to count wrong, but I hope this helps to give you an idea on what is going on

```
select 
   a.z, a.numrows / b.numrows as calc -- perhaps some error checking to avoid /0 error
from (select z, count(*) as numrows from tablea group by z) as a
    join 
 (select z, count(*) as numrows from tableb group by z) as b
     on a.z = b.z
```

Comment: I think the `count(*)` part is wrong because i'm not trying to count all of the rows but could I just swap that out? Also when you say `select z` or `group by z` do I have to specify `a.z` etc.?

Comment: Yeah, so the (select z, count(*) as numrows from tablea group by z) can be whatever it is you are trying to count there. What you are looking for in that bit is 2 columns, z and whatever it is you are counting.

Comment: I should add that count will just give you the number of rows. so you'd want a where statement if you are doing that, or a SUM if you are trying to add values in a column together, it really depends on you are trying to do there

Comment: But don't I have to specify which table z is coming from?

Comment: You do. I may be misinterpreting what you are trying to do here. Could you put some example data in your question? I feel my solution here isn't quite what you are after here

Comment: And shouldn't the `on a.z = b.z` part be `on tablea.z = tableb.z`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109490/discussion-between-lordbaconpants-and-nquestion).